# Why is this integral not correct?

Tags: calculus

The book says, "why is this not correct?"

$$\int_{-2}^1 x^{-4}\,dx=\frac{x^{-3}}{-3}\Big|_{-2}^1=\frac{-3}{8}.$$

It looks correct to me. It's just the fundamental theorem of calculus, right? What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you plot $x^{-4}$ in the interval $-2$ to $1$?

Comment: Why is it not correct? The integrand is never negative, but the integral is very negative. That should have set off alarm bells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integrand function has a vertical asymptote at $x=0$, which is on the interval from $[-2,1]$. Thus, we must break up the integral like this:

$$\int_{-2}^1 x^{-4}\,dx=\int_{-2}^0 x^{-4}\,dx+\int_{0}^1 x^{-4}\,dx$$

Try integrating again and applying the FTC. You'll find that the integral does not converge.

Patrick Stevens' comment provides great insight to the nonsensical nature of your "solution."

Answer (score 0):

Think of the graph of just $1/x^4$. What is its behaviour as $x \to 0$?

In fact, the integral $\int_{-2}^{0} x^{-4}$ diverges. Hence, the answer is incorrect